# Nuxt.js: How to include local images in Markdown blog content?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, markdown

I created a blog in Nuxt.js which uses Markdown for my articles. When writing my first article, I realized I can't include images in my markdown article from my `assets` folder. It only works if it's a link like the example below:

Markdown Image:

[image]

How can insert an image in Nuxt.js Markdown from this location? `assets/images/blog/trees.png`

Comment: When you say your blog use markdown. Do you mean using nuxt-content?

Comment: Yes, using nuxt-content.

Comment: I tried using `![alt text](~/assets/images/blog/trees.png)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You must reload webpack with `nuxt export`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like relative paths are not currently available: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/693#issuecomment-750412810

Only absolute paths should work after placing the image in the `/static` directory

```
![alt text](/images/blog/trees.png)
```

Comment: Crazy. Atinux answer this issue, but this is a fast response because you can use assets folder. You just need to run `nuxt export` each time you add an image in it. See here: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/106

Comment: Placing images in static folder and then including the images like this `![image alt text](/images/blog/trees.png)` worked! I only needed to include images locally not necessarily from assets folder.  Thank you @kissu.

Answer (score 5):

In your vue files, you can access images in `assets` folder with:

```html
<template>
  <img src="~/assets/your_image.png" />
</template>
```

In markdown file, you can do the same with Markdown syntax:

```markdown
![image alt text](~/assets/your_image.png)
```

But as your files in `content` folder is independent of webpack, you have to run `nuxt generate` each time you add a file in `assets` folder.

More info here:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets/
https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/106

Comment: I tried using `nuxt export` but still it wont show the image in my article. Its also says `nuxt export` is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, it's `nuxt generate` now

Comment: @ManUtopiK damn, generating a whole new project each time is really time consuming. Good if you know where to go but faster to specify it in the absolute way IMO.

Comment: How to add classes with this method?

Answer (score 4):

As of Nuxt 3, you can store images in the same folder as the markdown, with the [nuxt-content-assets](https://github.com/davestewart/nuxt-content-assets) module.

At run time, it copies all images found in content sources to a build-time folder, replaces any matching relative paths with public ones, and serves the images using Nitro.

At build time, images are copied to the final build output.

Answer (score 3):

place your images in static folder with this path :

```
static/images/img1.png
```

In markdown file, use this syntax:

```
![image alt text](/images/img1.png)
```

In vue files, use like this :

```
<template>
  <img src="/images/img1.png" />
</template>
```

or for use with **content** :

1- in content/articles/new-post.md :

```
---
title: Title
description: This is description
img: /images/img1.png
alt: Article 1
---

## Example
```

2- in vue file (pages/index.vue) :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="article of articles" :key="article.slug">
      <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
      <img
        v-if="article.img"
        class="h-48 xxlmin:w-1/2 xxlmax:w-full object-cover"
        :src="article.img"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const articles = await $content('articles', params.slug)
      .only(['title', 'description', 'img'])
      .fetch()

    return {
      articles,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

***notes*** :

1. place your images in static folder for example (static/images/*)
2. use '**/**' in start of addresses
   true  => /images/img1.png
   false => images/img1.png